# Magento Images on list.phtml

Tags: layout, magento, grid, php

I am looking to style product listing similar to that found here: http://www.diptyqueparis.com/personal-fragrances.html

CSS has only gotten me so far. My list.phtml is currently stock (from blank theme).
I am looking to have my first and last images to display in a different size as the rest of the product images and adjust the grid accordingly. Then I would assume I have to modify the ul to accommodate these changes, but can't do so on my own, and this is where I need help.

Any suggestions to get me going in the right (logical) direction would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

EDIT:  I am not editing any core files. This is in regards to the list.phtml found in the blank (or any) theme.

Answer (score 2):

One of the toughest parts about Magento is understanding the whole.  Invest some time in understanding the templating and design overrides.

Practicaly speaking:

- Create a new theme directory in your magento design director instance
- COPY the list.phtml into the same directory in that new design directory
- Make changes to your copy
- Specify the new theme directory in the design area of your config as an override

That's what you need to do in a nut shell.  Dont' just start changing the list.phtml in the Magento core...if you do, you'll regret it later :)

--- Later Addition ---

To achieve the layout, I would recommend putting in some sort of a "counter" that inserted some additional css class on the first and (in the case of your example) tenth item.

You can also edit the layout xml files to make your list display 10 at a time (if not through the config directly

Edit:

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $lastItem = 10; // added this line ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($i==0): ?> firstItem<?php elseif($i==($lastItem-1):?> lastItem<?php endif; // added this line ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments Chris. I am not editing the magento core list.phtml, rather the one from blank theme template. I am no expert in design overrides, but do understand the templates to a degree. I am looking for help on how to modify the template files to achieve this layout.

Comment: @SilverSlugger -- I added some additions to my answer, does this help?

Comment: This counter seems logical, but am not sure about how on how to code this. Can you or anyone provide a code sample?

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it in my list.phtml, but the second line seems to break the layout, as I am left with a mostly white screen. I am using 2columns-left and it removes both the main column as well as sidebar.